# Looking to set up an APNs server, on a raspberry pi. How would I get started? If this is possible

Tags: json, swift, server, raspberry-pi, apple-push-notifications

Basically the title.

I've written an application in Swift for iOS, and I plan to use push notifications.

I have a raspberry pi 3, and almost just for my own learning experience, I want to set up a server to send the JSON payloads to the Apple Push Notification service.

Using the `pusher` application, I can test the push notifications on my application.

However, I have no experience with anything server related.

Could anyone give me some pointers, or a tutorial on how I would get started with this?

Thanks!